# Getting cumulative sum using over and partition by not working

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get the cumulative sum of records until the value of 2 columns changes. Below is a sample of the data that I have now.

```html
DT                     ABBR_VOYAGE_OUT_N  ABBR_VESSEL_M
2017-05-08 16:00:00.000       0001W        rmhp tmvpn
2017-05-08 16:00:00.000       0001W        rmhp tmvpn
2017-05-09 20:00:00.000       0001W        rmhp tmvpn
2017-05-08 16:00:00.000       0002W        rmhp hueml
2017-05-08 16:00:00.000       0002W        rmhp hueml
2017-05-09 20:00:00.000       0002W        rmhp hueml

ETB_DT                 No_of_records
2017-05-10 12:00:00.000      17
2017-05-10 12:00:00.000      17
2017-05-10 12:00:00.000      10
2017-05-26 14:30:00.000      10        
2017-05-26 14:30:00.000      10        
2017-05-26 14:30:00.000      10
```

I am trying to sum up the number_of_records as a cumulative until the ABBR_VOYAGE_OUT_N and ABBR_VESSEL_M changes.

I have tried the below code but it is not working.

```html
select DT, ABBR_VOYAGE_OUT_N, ABBR_VESSEL_M,ETB_DT,No_of_records,
       sum(No_of_records) over (partition by ABBR_VOYAGE_OUT_N, ABBR_VESSEL_M order by ABBR_VOYAGE_OUT_N, ABBR_VESSEL_M ASC) as cumulative
from no_of_cntr
order by ABBR_VOYAGE_OUT_N,ABBR_VESSEL_M
```

It gives me the following output.

```html
DT                     ABBR_VOYAGE_OUT_N  ABBR_VESSEL_M
2017-05-08 16:00:00.000       0001W        rmhp tmvpn
2017-05-08 16:00:00.000       0001W        rmhp tmvpn
2017-05-09 20:00:00.000       0001W        rmhp tmvpn
2017-05-08 16:00:00.000       0002W        rmhp hueml
2017-05-08 16:00:00.000       0002W        rmhp hueml
2017-05-09 20:00:00.000       0002W        rmhp hueml

ETB_DT                 No_of_records cumulative
2017-05-10 12:00:00.000      17           44
2017-05-10 12:00:00.000      17           44
2017-05-10 12:00:00.000      10           44
2017-05-26 14:30:00.000      10           30
2017-05-26 14:30:00.000      10           30
2017-05-26 14:30:00.000      10           30
```

Below is the desired output that I am trying to get.

```html
DT                     ABBR_VOYAGE_OUT_N  ABBR_VESSEL_M
2017-05-08 16:00:00.000       0001W        rmhp tmvpn
2017-05-08 16:00:00.000       0001W        rmhp tmvpn
2017-05-09 20:00:00.000       0001W        rmhp tmvpn
2017-05-08 16:00:00.000       0002W        rmhp hueml
2017-05-08 16:00:00.000       0002W        rmhp hueml
2017-05-09 20:00:00.000       0002W        rmhp hueml

ETB_DT                  No_of_records cumulative
2017-05-10 12:00:00.000      17           17
2017-05-10 12:00:00.000      17           34
2017-05-10 12:00:00.000      10           44
2017-05-26 14:30:00.000      10           10
2017-05-26 14:30:00.000      10           20
2017-05-26 14:30:00.000      10           30
```

Do you have any ideas why I am not getting the correct output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add a cte at the beginning in order to consider the order in which the partitioning has to be done:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(
  Dt DATETIME
 ,ABBR_VOYAGE_OUT_N NVARCHAR(20)
 ,ABBR_VESSEL_M NVARCHAR(20)
 ,ETB_DT DATETIME
 ,No_of_records INT
)

INSERT INTO @t VALUES('2017-05-08 16:00:00.000', '0001W', 'rmhp tmvpn', '2017-05-10 12:00:00.000', 17);
INSERT INTO @t VALUES('2017-05-08 16:00:00.000', '0001W', 'rmhp tmvpn', '2017-05-10 12:00:00.000', 17);
INSERT INTO @t VALUES('2017-05-09 20:00:00.000', '0001W', 'rmhp tmvpn', '2017-05-10 12:00:00.000', 10);
INSERT INTO @t VALUES('2017-05-08 16:00:00.000', '0002W', 'rmhp hueml', '2017-05-26 14:30:00.000', 10);       
INSERT INTO @t VALUES('2017-05-08 16:00:00.000', '0002W', 'rmhp hueml', '2017-05-26 14:30:00.000', 10);       
INSERT INTO @t VALUES('2017-05-09 20:00:00.000', '0002W', 'rmhp hueml', '2017-05-26 14:30:00.000', 10);

WITH cte AS(
  SELECT DT, ABBR_VOYAGE_OUT_N, ABBR_VESSEL_M,ETB_DT,No_of_records, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DT, ETB_DT) AS rn
    FROM @t
)
select DT, ABBR_VOYAGE_OUT_N, ABBR_VESSEL_M,ETB_DT,No_of_records,
       sum(No_of_records) over (partition by ABBR_VOYAGE_OUT_N, ABBR_VESSEL_M ORDER BY rn) as cumulative
from cte
order by ABBR_VOYAGE_OUT_N,ABBR_VESSEL_M
```

Comment: Thank you so much this helped me!

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similatr with orders on my system.....

I think you need to look at "ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW"

Here is my query for my orders, hopefully it will help you sort your one out....

```
SELECT 
  SaleMonth, Month_Order_Count, MonthTotal,   
  SUM(Month_Order_Count) OVER(ORDER BY SaleMonth **ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW**) AS Cumulative_Order_Count,
  SUM(MonthTotal) OVER(ORDER BY SaleMonth **ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW**) AS Cumulative_Order_Value
FROM 
(
  SELECT SUB_Q.SaleMonth, Count( DISTINCT SUB_Q.OrderID) as Month_Order_Count, SUM(Value) as MonthTotal  FROM
  (
    SELECT CONCAT( DatePart( year, OH.OrderDate), '-', FORMAT( OH.OrderDate, 'MM')) as SaleMonth,
    OI.OrderID,
    OI.Value
  FROM ORDERHEADER OH 
  INNER JOIN OrderItem OI ON OI.OrderID = OH.OrderID
  INNER JOIN ECodeOrder ECO ON ECO.OrderId = OH.ORDERID
  ) SUB_Q
  GROUP BY SUB_Q.SaleMonth
)TOTALS_Q
ORDER BY SaleMonth
```